# Get Ember/Broccoli-Sass to parse .sass files

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm trying to set up my first Ember project with ember-cli und want to include SASS by using .sass files (not .scss files). Out of the box it only parses a app.scss. How can I achive to parse a app.sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

broccoli-sass was just recently updated to provide support for .sass files/syntax. Support for this was added to ember-cli [in this pull request](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/1367) but that version has not been released (0.0.40).

If you want to use this feature now you can follow [the instructions for working with master](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli#working-with-master).